# Angular 5: Access a non-global service from a route guard

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

In my app I have a parent route with a series of child routes:

```
{
  path: 'parent',
  component: ParentComponent,
  children: [
    { path: 'child1', component: Child1 },
    { path: 'child2', component: Child2 }
  ]
}
```

I have a non-global service (MyService) setup as a provider in the ParentComponent, which is injected into both of the child components.

Now I want to add a route guard to the second child component, making the route definition like this:

```
{
  path: 'parent',
  component: ParentComponent,
  children: [
    { path: 'child1', component: Child1 },
    { path: 'child2', component: Child2, canActivate: [MyGuard] }
  ]
}
```

How can I access MyService from within `MyGuard`? If I try to inject it in normally, I get the `no provider for MyService` error.

I see the `canActivate` route guard can accept an `route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot` parameter, and this parameter has a `component` property. However, this property isn't an instance of the component, it just seems to be the class definition for the component. Am I supposed to create an instance of the component myself?

How can I get access to the service I require?

Comment: Are you set @Injectable() to MyGuard?

Comment: Yes, I have added the `@Injectable()` decorator to the guard

Comment: Here is same question but it's don't have answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45921454/angular4-use-components-service-in-guard