# Why do I have to use AlertModule.forRoot() in imports of an NgModule?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using `AlertModule` from `ng2-bootstrap`. In the `imports` section if I just use `AlertModule` I get the error `Value: Error: No provider for AlertConfig!`. If I use `AlertModule.forRoot()` the application works fine. Why?

My app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {AlertModule} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule, 

   // AlertModule, /*doesn't work*/
    AlertModule.forRoot() /*it works!*/
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`forRoot` named static functions have their [**own purpose**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39653072/how-to-use-forroot-within-feature-modules-hierarchy). They are used for application level singleton services.

`AlertModule` does not have any providers in it. When you call `forRoot`, it returns an object of type **[ModuleWithProviders](https://angular.io/api/core/ModuleWithProviders)** which includes the `AlertModule` itself with it's declarations and also providers which are used in `AlertModule`.

This is what is written in the [**AlertModule - github source**](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/alert/alert.module.ts)

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertComponent } from './alert.component';
import { AlertConfig } from './alert.config';

@NgModule({
   imports: [CommonModule],
   declarations: [AlertComponent],
   exports: [AlertComponent],
   entryComponents: [AlertComponent]
})
export class AlertModule {
   static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
     return { ngModule: AlertModule, providers: [AlertConfig] };
   }
}
```

Look that providers section of `NgModule` is missed. This means if you import only `AlertModule` the `providers` are not provided. But when you call `forRoot` on it, it returns the `AlertModule` addition with provider `AlertConfig`.