# How can I localize my Angular 11 library?

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular-localize

I'm refactoring my Angular 11 application into libraries. My regular application is localized using `@angular/localize` as a dev dependency, so I have made use of the `$localize` directive in part of my code. I need to move this code with this directive into a library, but I can't figure out how to do this.

In my library's `package.json` file, I've added a peer-dependency on `@angular/localize` to match the devDependency in my application:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~11.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

However the compiler reports that it can't find `$localize` when I try to do `ng build <library name>`.

```
× Compiling TypeScript sources through NGC
ERROR: projects/example/src/lib/example.service.ts:52:23 - error TS2304: Cannot find name '$localize'.

52         description = $localize `example localized text`;
                         ~~~~~~~~~
```

How can I use the `$localize` directive in my library?

```
>ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 11.0.1
Node: 12.18.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 11.0.0
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... localize, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1100.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1100.1
@angular-devkit/core            11.0.1
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.0.1
@angular/cli                    11.0.1
@schematics/angular             11.0.1
@schematics/update              0.1100.1
ng-packagr                      11.0.3
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.0.5
```

Comment: Also whoever vtc'd for "needs debugging details" please indicate what specifically you need since I included the code, the package.json, and the specific error produced when running `ng build <library name>`.

Answer (score 12):

**First**: install `@angular/localize` package.

```
npm i @angular/localize -D
```

**Second**: Find `entryFile` in your `ng-package.json` file, in my case `public-api.ts`

```json
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/ngx-my-lib",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts" // <=== this line
  }
}
```

**Third**: add `import '@angular/localize/init';` to your `entryFile`, in my case `public-api.ts`

```json
import '@angular/localize/init'; // <=== this line

export * from './lib/ngx-my-lib.service';
export * from './lib/ngx-my-lib.component';
export * from './lib/ngx-my-lib.module';
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Works on Angular 9+.

Comment: This works; but it looks like you may also have to include the import in the entry point of any components you set up in a separate sub-module.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, try to add this to your entry file:

```
import '@angular/localize/init';
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'entry file'? `public-api.ts` possibly? Adding the import there didn't help.

Comment: yes.  'entry file' as it is defined in ng-package.json  lib.entryFile.
After adding import '@angular/localize/init' , i can build and publish

Answer (score 2):

You have to put `import '@angular/localize/init';` inside `src/polyfills.ts` of the main project. Also have to configure the `angular.json` for your main project (not the library) to be able to use the localization.

You have to configure the `angular.json` like so depending on your locales:

```json
"projects": {
    "the-name-of-your-project": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "i18n": {
        "sourceLocale": "en-US",
        "locales": {
          "fr": "fr-messages.xlf"
        }
      },
      ...
      "architect": {
        ...
        "configurations": {
            "fr": { "localize": ["fr"] },
            ...
         }
      },
      "serve": {
          ...
          "configurations": {
            "fr": {
                "browserTarget": "angular-material-timepicker:build:fr"
              }
           }
           ...
       }

}
```

You can check out the different sections that I had in my project and with which everything was working by clicking these links: [1](https://github.com/IliaIdakiev/angular-material-timepicker/blob/ed5a36a97562692dce4669301d21c5ad06fcc7c6/angular.json#L13), [2](https://github.com/IliaIdakiev/angular-material-timepicker/blob/ed5a36a97562692dce4669301d21c5ad06fcc7c6/angular.json#L43), [3](https://github.com/IliaIdakiev/angular-material-timepicker/blob/ed5a36a97562692dce4669301d21c5ad06fcc7c6/angular.json#L93) or view the whole [file](https://github.com/IliaIdakiev/angular-material-timepicker/blob/ed5a36a97562692dce4669301d21c5ad06fcc7c6/angular.json).

The problem with this approach is that if you have it as a dependency, all the users of your library will have to install it and put and configure it manually as well, even if they don't need it.

I'm managing this [angular material timepicker module](https://github.com/IliaIdakiev/angular-material-timepicker) and I removed this dependency in favour of using [this - Mark element attributes for translations](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#mark-element-attributes-for-translations). Notice the **i18n-title** attribute:

```
<img [src]="logo" i18n-title title="Angular logo" />
```

So now all users have to do is just use the `i18n-<name_of_input>` and everything works fine and you don't need to bother dealing with `localize`.

So if your library component/directive has an input lets say title that you want to be translated you can just put `i18n-title="some title|An introduction title for this sample@@introductionComponent"` and everything works great.

Comment: The import statement is already in the application's polyfills (the existing app is already localized). The code I'm moving into a library uses the `$localize` directive; I'm trying to not actually change any of the implementation, just move it.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I've updated my answer with the additional configurations that are needed for the `angular.json` that I've previously missed. Do you have those?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by:

1. Creating a `typings.d.ts` file next to the library's **src** folder.
2. Put inside: `declare function $localize(messageParts: TemplateStringsArray, ...expressions: readonly any[]): string;`

Error disappear and compiler finds the translation parts with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `@angular/localize` package first

```
npm install @angular/localize
```

Then, try importing `@angular/localize/init` in your `polyfills.ts` file

```
import @angular/localize/init
```