# Angular library, Cannot find name $localize

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, nrwl, nomachine-nx

I'm refactoring my Angular 11 application into libraries using Nx tool. My main app have `@angular/localize` as dependency and `@angular/localize` import in `polyfills.ts`. Every usage of `$localize` in my library code generates Typescript error `TS2304: Cannot find name '$localize'`. My libraries don't have their own `package.json` file. Application build works without error. It's looks like Typescript typings problem. Any ideas?

library tsconfig.lib.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../../dist/out-tsc",
    "target": "es2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json in library

```
{
  "extends": "../../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "files": [],
  "include": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.lib.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

angular version

```
Angular CLI: 11.1.1
Node: 14.15.4
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 11.1.0
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... elements, forms, language-service, localize, material
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: <error>

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1002.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1101.1
@angular-devkit/core            10.2.1
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.0.7
@angular/cli                    11.1.1
@schematics/angular             11.0.7
@schematics/update              0.1101.1
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.1.3
```

Comment: How did you resolve this issue? The below solution didn't work for me.

Comment: I had to add `import '@angular/localize/init';` in my `test-setup.ts` file to get the tests running. The build ran after importing `import './polyfills';` in my `index.ts`. Maybe this helps you finding a solution to your problem even if my issue was not exactly the same as yours.

Answer (score 4):

I came here looking for an answer, but somehow stumbled upon a solution on my way. In my project, the workspace/projects TS version is slightly different than VS Code's version (4.4.4 vs 4.5.4) which will sometimes cause these non-issues.

Background aside, in my scenario, all I had to do was pull up the command palette, type in/select "TypeScript: Select TypeScript Version..." and set it back to reference the workspace version.

Answer (score 4):

I tried adding i18n support to my library when I stumbled on this problem.
Adding `import '@angular/localize/init';` public-api.ts instead of pollyfill.ts did the trick for me.

Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68334503/10031161

Answer (score 1):

The import of @angular/localize/init may cause a tslint error for no-import-side-effect because it adds to the global context (that is, a side effect). To fix this error, add the following to your tslint.config

"no-import-side-effect": [
true,
{
"ignore-module": "(core-js/.*|zone\.js/.*|@angular/localize/init)$"
}
]

Answer (score 1):

### Simply use the Angular CLI for adding the dependency

To add this dependency properly to your project simply adding the dependency to your `package.json` is not sufficient.
You will need to run the following command with the angular CLI to add the library correctly to your application:

```
ng add @angular/localize
```

I had the same problem and running this command resolved these typescript typing issues.

It seems to add the `@angular/localize` type definitions to your `tsconfig` file as follows:

```
"types": [
  "@angular/localize"
],
```

After rerunning your application all typing issues will be resolved.